# línea 3: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `('

Tags: c++

empecé con c++ hace poco, y quise intentar probar lo que aprendí, pero no me salió, escribí:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

   std::cout << "Hello World";

}
```

pero me sale un error:

> línea 3: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `('
>
> línea 3: `int main() {'

Comment: ¿ Como lo estás intentando compilar ? Línea de comandos **exacta**, por favor.

Comment: lo primero que hice fue escribir: "g++ test.cpp" después lo ejecute con "./test.cpp"

Comment: Comprueba si al hacer `g++ test.cpp` ha aparecido un archivo nuevo en ese mismo directorio. Ese archivo es el que tienes que ejecutar. Si no recuerdo mal, se llamará `a.out`.

Comment: gracias! realmente me ayudaste!

Comment: Estás intentando "ejecutar" el fuente en vez de el compilado. El fuente normalmente no tiene permisos de ejecución, así que supongo que se los has dado tú con un `chmod +x`. Al intentar ejecutar un "fuente", el sistema asume que es un script para el shell, y usa el shell para ejecutarlo. Es por tanto el shell el que encuentra un error en la línea 3 , pues la sintaxis de ese archivo no es la de un shell script válido (la línea 1 la toma por un comentario y la ignora).

Comment: Lo típico es usar la opción `-o` al compilar para darle un nombre al ejecutable resultante (si no se llamará `a.out` por defecto). Así que puedes hacer `g++ -o test test.cpp` y el ejecutable se llamará `test` tras lo cual podrás probarlo con `./test`

Answer (score 4):

Está intentando ejecutar el código fuente (test.cpp) en lugar de su archivo ejecutable compilado. Ejecuta el siguiente comando para compilar test.cpp.

```
g++ test.cpp
```

La salida de `g++ test.cpp` es un archivo ejecutable que se llama por defecto a.out. Ejecuta el siguiente comando para salidar los resultados del código C++.

```
./a.out
```

La salida será más fácil de leer si agrega `<< std::endl` al final de la tercera línea del código para mostrar la salida en una nueva línea.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```